# Regular Expression excluding of expression like int keyword

Tags: c#, regex, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I've written a mini scanner for a compiler and it reads from a file and I want to write instead of variables, id and for keywords do nothing (a group of words that want exclude from my variable form expressions), below line get my variable, how can I exclude for example `int` or `bool` or ... from this expression:

```
((?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a zero width negative lookahead I think.  The syntax in C# regex is to group the expression you don't want to match in a zero width negative lookahead.  Also you probably need to delimit the expressing with word boundaries `\b`:

```
string pattern = @"(\b(?!int|bool)(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b)";
```

Comment: your expression for example just omit 'b' from bool but i want to omit all "bool" as a word.

Comment: please help me because im new at regular expression and have a project on it,thanks.

Comment: @user3356317 I updated the example with an expression I tested.

Comment: bu when i wnat add it to my c# code it doesen't replace correctly but in a online regular expression tester it works,my code is:

Comment: string pattern = "(\b(?!int|bool)(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b)";
            string replacement = "id";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            this.lines[index] = rgx.Replace(this.lines[index], replacement);

Comment: You'll have to be more specific... it works for me. Every word in the line that is not a keyword gets replaced with the string "id"

Comment: please test below code,it doesn't work with this regular expression but work with pas expressions:

Comment: string test = "int Hello :=   2 ;";
                    string pattern = "\b(?!int|bool)(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b";
                    string replacement = "Id";
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                    string newline = rgx.Replace(test, replacement);

Comment: The issue is that your `\b` is being escaped before being handled by Regex.  You need to either make the string a string literal by prefixing with @ like this: (`string pattern = @"\b(?!int|bool)(?:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\b"`), or double escape the `\b` like this: `\\b`